# Gridify gallery height not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, gridify

I want to make a jQuery grid gallery and found after many libraries "gridify" which is simple to use and works for me. The problem is that the height of the gallery isn't recognized.

Of course I could make after it a div with some height then put following stuff but in responsive case when the pictures are like all in a column it doesn't work anymore.

Anyway, the library gives some examples which do the same, it's this way : http://cssdeck.com/labs/wiu0xg4b

Do you have any idea about how I could manage to get the height recognized ? Or if you have any other library that is also easy to use and which hasnt that problem, it's fine for me too

.

The library : https://github.com/hongkhanh/gridify

Thank you !

Comment: Could you give the HTML/JS you currently have?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, the code I mean.

Comment: As I said it's the same way as here : http://cssdeck.com/labs/wiu0xg4b it renders the same and also here when I inspect the div that contains the pictures it not including all of them